# Can I use free Postgres tier with Standard 1X Heroku plan?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I am currently using Hobby dev plan, and will soon switch to Standard 1X. Will I still be able to use the current postgres DB (free one) or I need to upgrade as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can totally use the free db with the standard or hobby dynos. There is no forced link between these plans.